# Oracle JRE 1.8_281 GUI freeze

Tags: java, windows, swing, freeze

I'm looking for help to solve a problem.
I'm developping a swing application using DockingFrames (no more supported in spite it's a verry nice lib).
Since oracle JRE 1.8_281 - test on Windows only, on file DragEnter, my applicaiton freeze.
There is no more output on all logguer (the list is big : java.awt.focus.Component, java.awt.focus.Component, java.awt.focus.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager, all focus event to summary).
When freeze appear, no more event are triggered.
At debug time, using eclpise, application could be pause.
No blocked thread appear in stack, the AWT Thread is always in WInputMethod.endCompositionNative() when the freeze appear.

```
    Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended)   
        owns: InputMethodContext  (id=98)   
        owns: Component$AWTTreeLock  (id=99)    
        WInputMethod.endCompositionNative(int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
        WInputMethod.endComposition() line: 456 
        InputMethodContext(InputContext).endComposition() line: 913 
        InputMethodContext(InputContext).focusGained(Component) line: 321   
        InputMethodContext(InputContext).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 245  
        InputMethodContext.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 196    
        StackDockStation$Background(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 4821   
        StackDockStation$Background(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 2297   
        StackDockStation$Background(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 4711   
        DefaultKeyboardFocusManager(KeyboardFocusManager).redispatchEvent(Component, AWTEvent) line: 1954   
        DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Component, AWTEvent) line: 1015 
        DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 639   
        StackDockStation$Background(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 4760   
        StackDockStation$Background(Container).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 2297   
        StackDockStation$Background(Component).dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 4711
```

This bug is not reproduced on Java OpneJDK jre-8.0.282.08-hotspot or JDK 11.
The bug is stil present whith last Oracle JRE 1.8_292.

I'dont know if the problem is du to my application or JRE.
Any suggestion to find what is blocking my applicaion ?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Nadine

Answer (score 1):

Please check this little program:

```
public class SwingFrame extends JFrame {
    public SwingFrame() {
        super("Demo");
        add(new JTextField());
        setSize(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new SwingFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

This program freezes on drag enter if the JTextField is focused (since JDK 8 281)
The workaround for me: Setting the focus on another Component (e.g. a JButton) on window deactivation.

```
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    button1.requestFocus();
    System.out.println("The window has been deactivated");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i try you test case and succeed to drag over without freeze. Is this related to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8262446 ? Unfortunatly this workaround is not applicable in my GUI since FocusEvent are catched and managed by DockingFrames